# HV to ADC interface for Photodiode pulses

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, circuit-design, photodiode

Reduced circuit for simplicty. LHS circuit models SPAD pulses in response to photon pulses.

My issue is that I need to acquire cathode output from HV and to condition it to ADC, say FSR=5V. I'm looking for a simple but effective way not to destroy opamp (way too high CM)

A level-shifter may be an option but if ICs could spared it'd better.

Cf is for compensation otherwise I find amplifier's input capacitance to low-pass the output too much. Clearly resistive divider must be high enough not to load the response, however this also brings signal degradation. It doesn't seem best to me to attenuate-then-amplify (with another inverting towards ADC)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why would a resistive divider degrade the signal?

Comment: @RonaldB: the overall capacitance discharges through Rd, but then recharges through R_L = 100k which must be big to get enough voltage drop. So the divider is in parallel and shouldn't alter that.

Comment: Why is Vak changing so much? If I'm not mistaken, a SPAD only works very close to the rated voltage. Should the amplifier then also sense by AC coupling (highpass)? Are you reading average level (in which case, anode current could be sensed via shunt resistor) or only interested in pulses?

Comment: @TimWilliams: the idea is to sample the entire waveform, stepped down of course. As per Vak, it is fast decreasing due to Rd (1k). If I may provide any other detail, please let me know.

Comment: Well, I can see that. No, I mean will the SPAD even work down to such voltages?  Will you be able to resolve such large pulses, or clustered so closely?

Comment: @TimWilliams: Yes, the idea is indeed to lower its rev bias around Vbd such that the avalanche is quenched won (which happens above Vbd). This is done passively through RL (kind of NFB), but now there're Active solutions. Though this is just an example/toy project.